# Simple Neural-Network that gives the summation of the input variables as output in Python?

Tags: python, neural-network

Can some please make a Simple Neural Network that give the summation of the input variables as the output.
Example if input variables are X1, X2, X3 then the output is Y= X1 + X2 + X3.

Simple Python Program, using matrix multiplication would be helpful.

Thank You.

Here is the code I am trying to apply it is just a modified version of "iamtrask" code, but it is not giving me right answer and tends to saturate at [1.] when I increase the test cases(set_size).

```
import numpy as np

outputs=[]

#initializinf hyper parameters
set_size=20
iterations=10000
input_variables=3

# sigmoid function
def nonlin(x, deriv=False):
    if (deriv == True):
        return 1 * (1 - x)
    return  1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

#inverse of sigmoid, Logit function
def logit(x):
   return np.log(x/(1-x))

#initializing inputs with random values
inputs = 2 * np.random.random((set_size, input_variables)) - 1
X=np.array(inputs)

#Getting desired output using mathematical operations
for h in range(set_size):
    outputs.append(nonlin((X[h][0]) + (X[h][1]) + (X[h][2])))



# output dataset
y = np.array([outputs]).T # converting list into array and taking transpose

# seed random numbers to make calculation
# deterministic (just a good practice)
np.random.seed(1)

# initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2 * np.random.random((input_variables, set_size)) - 1
syn1 = 2 * np.random.random((set_size, 1)) - 1
print(y)

for iter in range(0,10000):
    # forward propagation
    l0 = X
    l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0, syn0))
    l2 = nonlin(np.dot(l1, syn1))
    # how much did we miss?
    #l1_error = y - l1
    l2_error = y - l2
    #print(l1_error)

    l2_delta = l2_error * nonlin(l2, deriv=True)

    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1, deriv=True)
    # multiply how much we missed by the
    # slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
    #l1_delta = l1_error * nonlin(l1, True)

    # update weights
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
print("Output After Training:")
#out=logit(l2)
print(l2)

#testing the trained network with new values
X1=input("Enter the new inputs:")
mynums = [float(i) for i in X1.split()]
#mynums = map(float, X1.split())
print(mynums)
l0 = mynums
l1 = nonlin(np.dot(l0, syn0))
l2 = nonlin(np.dot(l1, syn1))
print(l2)
```

Comment: What have you done until now?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a website where we write code for you. It's a place where we help you debug your own code when you've run into a wall. You can do this!

Comment: Ok, so I have added the code I am trying to modify and Run.

Answer (score 1):

"A bare bones neural network implementation to describe the inner workings of backpropagation." 11 lines of code!

```
X = np.array([ [0,0,1],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,1] ])
y = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1
for j in xrange(60000):
    l1 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(X,syn0))))
    l2 = 1/(1+np.exp(-(np.dot(l1,syn1))))
    l2_delta = (y - l2)*(l2*(1-l2))
    l1_delta = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T) * (l1 * (1-l1))
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += X.T.dot(l1_delta)
```

http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified Trask's code this way:

```
import numpy as np

# sigmoid function
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

# input dataset of 100 pairs of X1, X2 & X3 numbers lying between 1 and 3
X = np.random.randint(1,3,size=(100,3)).astype(int) 
#Rescaling them or Normalizing them
X = X/(3*3)    #(Max_element, No_of_imputs)
# output dataset            
y = np.sum(X, axis = 1, keepdims=True)
#Normalizing
y=y/(3*3)

#Initializing weights
np.random.seed(1)

# randomly initialize our weights with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,4)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((4,1)) - 1

#Training
for iter in range(30000):

    # forward propagation
    l0 = X
    l1 = nonlinn(np.dot(l0,syn0))
    l2 = nonlinn(np.dot(l1,syn1))

    # how much did we miss?
    l2_error = y-l2

    #if (iter% 100) == 0:
    #    print ("Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(l2_error))))

    l2_delta = l2_error*nonlinn(l2, deriv=True)

    l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

    # multiply how much we missed by the 
    # slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
    l1_delta = l1_error * nonlinn(l1,True)

    # update weights
    syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
    syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)

#Predict
l0 = [[3,1,0]]    #Should give 4 as answer
l1 = nonlinn(np.dot(l0,syn0))
l2 = nonlinn(np.dot(l1,syn1))
print (l2*(3*3))  
#(3*3) will invert the effect of normalization
```

The result was 4.157 (quite accurate).
I think the issue was with normalization.